# Identifying Firefox Add On from Native Mac Application

Tags: macos, firefox, websocket, firefox-addon

I am developing a firefox web extension (Add On) which communicates with my Native Mac Application through "Socket Connection". I got stuck with the requirement to authorise the Client (Socket client from firefox add on) as I am unable to find out a unique identifier for my unpacked firefox add on.

I am trying to map the unique Id in the application side so that I can check whether the add on with same Id is trying to connect to the Socket server which would be restricted in case of unauthorised Identifier.

The identifier that comes along with Origin header in the connection request is Internal UUID of the add on which changes on each installation as per Firefox documentation.

I welcome an answer that could guide me to choose a perfect unique identifier or different approach that could validate the add on.

Answer (score 1):

To have it work in this scenario, you will need to add in the applications key in manifest.json

Once you have finished developing the extension, you can package it and submit it to AMO for review and signing. If the packaged extension you upload does not contain an ID, AMO will generate one for you. It's only at this point that the add-on will be assigned a permanent ID, which will be embedded in the signed packaged extension.

Check out [MDN webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Package_your_extension_) for the full information on that though. They have full guides on how to use AMO as well.

Comment: Is there any way I could do this for an unpacked Add On in development phase. For chrome packing extension from the chrome itself will create a Unique Id. Is that possible here?

Comment: If you install it and just refresh firefox will retain the key issued at install. If you restart the app though it will get a new ID that is really all they give you in the basic firefox. If your needing more though you could always generate it with AMO API [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/WebExtensions_and_the_Add-on_ID#When_do_you_need_an_add-on_ID

Comment: I have tried signing the add On , The point you made is correct that extension id is set as per the manifest.json. But the internal UUID which has been sent over header details is still not uniform across browsers. Any suggestions?

Comment: @VikasKrishnan, sadly, you must package your extension separately for each browser.  I wrote a script which packages my extensions for Firefox, Chrome and Opera, producing these three products for each extension.

Comment: @JerryKrinock I am clear on the topic that I should sign it separately. My problem is: I need to allow connection request at my mac application from my extension only. No one should be able to mock the client settings and could connect to my server. I need a unique identifier which should be available or accessible while the client tries to connect.... The Origin header so far available is not uniform across the browsers and changes per installation as well.